# How to tile up to 4 windows in MacOS?

Tags: macos, monterey

I want to tile 3-4 windows on my screen. I don't know how to do this. I tried doing it by first tiling 2 windows and then the same for the third. However, that did not work. I did find one work-around and that was using shortcuts. But for that, I have to open shortcuts and then click on tile 3/4 windows option.

I am looking for a quicker way to do the same. I am NOT looking for any third party apps for the same (as I have seen other answers on this site suggesting). Please suggest me a *quick* **built-in** way to tile at least 3-4 windows (kind of like in Windows 11).

Comment: There are several questions with answers regarding window managment alredy on this site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've seen a few of the answers. They all say use so and so app to do it. I want a proper built-in way of doing the same.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a built-in way for this. But please edit some details on which specific things you've looked at into your question and ask specifically for a built-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said no third-party apps, but rectangle is completely free and works admirably. Link: https://rectangleapp.com/